# Имитация бегущей зеленой строки на монохромном экране

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать имитацию зеленой бегущей строки на монохромном экране, как было до появления цветных дисплеев и современных ОС.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 19):

*Для более комфортного просмотра откройте - "На всю страницу"*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
 
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id ='NewYear'></canvas>
<script>
  var db = document.body;
  var c = document.getElementById('NewYear');
  var $ = c.getContext('2d');
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
  var resume;
  function relay(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(relay);
  resume();
}
</script>
  <!--Script to Relay!-->
<script>
  //BEGIN SCRIPT RELAY TO ru.StackOverflow.com... 
  
  _s = db.querySelectorAll("script")[1].innerHTML.split("\n");
  x = 0; 
  y = 1; 
  c.width = w = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = h = _s.length*20;
  db.style.margin = 0;
  db.style.background = "hsla(0,0%,0%,1)";
  db.style.overflow = "hidden";
  $.textBaseline = "top";
  $.font = "1.1em monospace";
  
//PAUSE RELAY: ...
// ПУСТЬ ИНОСТРАННЫЕ ГОСТИ УДИВЛЯЮТСЯ И
// СПРАШИВАЮТ ВАС, ЧТО ЭТО ЗНАЧИТ:
//СО СТАРЫМ НОВЫМ  2018 ГОДОМ! 
// УДАЧИ И ВЕЗЕНИЯ ВО ВСЕХ НАЧИНАНИЯХ, КАК В ВИРТУАЛЬНОМ,
// ТАК И В РЕАЛЬНОМ МИРЕ!
/*
          ★ 
         *o* 
        *♥*o*
       ***o*** 
      **o**♥*o* 
     **♥**o**o** 
    **o**♥***♥*o* 
   *****♥*o**o**** 
  **♥**o*****o**♥** 
 ******o*****♥**o*** 
****o***♥**o***o***♥ 
        || 
  \____ ||_____/
╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬ 
  
*/

  
resume = function(){
    $.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    $.shadowBlur = 0; $.fillStyle = "hsla(0,0%,0%,0.4)";
    $.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    $.shadowColor = "hsla(120,100%,50%,0.5)";
    $.shadowBlur = 9; $.fillStyle = "hsla(120,100%,20%,1)";
    $.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
  _s.forEach(function(t, i) {
      if (i <= y) {
        if (i == y) { t = t.substr(0, x); }
        $.fillText(t, 100, 100+i*16);  }
 });
                 
 $.fillStyle = "hsla(120,100%,50%,1)";
 $.fillRect(100+$.measureText(_s[y].substr(0, x)).width, 102+y*16, 10, 14);
 x++;
  if (x >= _s[y].length) { y++; x = 0;}
   if (y*16 > innerHeight-340) { $.translate(0, -0.5);}
    if (y >= _s.length-1) { window.clearInterval();}}
  
relay();
  

</script>

</body>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Скрипт нашёл на своем компьютере. Когда-то скачал. Сейчас не смог найти ссылку на первоисточник.

Кто укажет верную ссылку, добавлю.  Немного  доработал скрипт, чтобы срабатывал без ошибок в нашем сниппете.
 Добавил поздравления участникам stackoverflow.
 Особая благодарность за [Ёлочку](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) @Hamster

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e07zpbvh/)

**Вариант графики Алексея Шиманского**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e07zpbvh/1/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
 
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id ='NewYear'></canvas>
<script>
  var db = document.body;
  var c = document.getElementById('NewYear');
  var $ = c.getContext('2d');
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
  var resume;
  function relay(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(relay);
  resume();
}
</script>
  <!--Script to Relay!-->
<script>
  //BEGIN SCRIPT RELAY TO ru.StackOverflow.com... 
  
  _s = db.querySelectorAll("script")[1].innerHTML.split("\n");
  x = 0; 
  y = 1; 
  c.width = w = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = h = _s.length*20;
  db.style.margin = 0;
  db.style.background = "hsla(0,0%,0%,1)";
  db.style.overflow = "hidden";
  $.textBaseline = "top";
  $.font = "1.1em monospace";
  
//PAUSE RELAY: ...
//СО СТАРЫМ НОВЫМ  2018 ГОДОМ!  
// УДАЧИ И ВЕЗЕНИЯ ВО ВСЕХ НАЧИНАНИЯХ, КАК В ВИРТУАЛЬНОМ,
// ТАК И В РЕАЛЬНОМ МИРЕ!
/*
█▀█░░█░█░█▀█░█▀█░█░░░█░█▀▄▀█ 
█░▄░░█▀█░█░█░█▀▄░█▀█░█░█░█░█ 
▀▀▀░░▀░▀░▀▀▀░▀▀▀░▀▀▀░▀░▀░░░▀ 
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 
░█▀▀░█▀█░░█▀█░░█▀█░█▀▄▀█░░█░ 
░█░░░█░█░░█░█░░█░█░█░█░█░░▀░ 
░▀░░░▀▀▀░█▀▀▀█░▀▀▀░▀░░░▀░░▀░ 
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 
░░▀██────██▀───────────█▀▀░░ 
░░──█▀█▀██────────────█───░░ 
░░──█▄█▄███████████████───░░ 
░░───███──▐████████████───░░ 
░░────▀───▄██─▄██───▄██───░░ 
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 
░░█▀▀▀█░█▀▀▀▀█░██▀██░█▀▀▀▀█░ 
░░█▄█░█░█░██░█░█▄░██░█░▀▀░█░ 
░░█░▄██░█░██░█░██░██░█░██░█░ 
░░█▄▄▄█░█▄▄▄▄█░█▄▄▄█░█▄▄▄▄█░
  
*/

  
resume = function(){
    $.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    $.shadowBlur = 0; $.fillStyle = "hsla(0,0%,0%,0.4)";
    $.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    $.shadowColor = "hsla(120,100%,50%,0.5)";
    $.shadowBlur = 9; $.fillStyle = "hsla(120,100%,20%,1)";
    $.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
  _s.forEach(function(t, i) {
      if (i <= y) {
        if (i == y) { t = t.substr(0, x); }
        $.fillText(t, 100, 100+i*16);  }
 });
                 
 $.fillStyle = "hsla(120,100%,50%,1)";
 $.fillRect(100+$.measureText(_s[y].substr(0, x)).width, 102+y*16, 10, 14);
 x++;
  if (x >= _s[y].length) { y++; x = 0;}
   if (y*16 > innerHeight-340) { $.translate(0, -0.5);}
    if (y >= _s.length-1) { window.clearInterval();}}
  
relay();
  

</script>

</body>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: чертов сниппет сломал всю ёлку

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну да. Бился, бился и это максимум, чего смог сделать JSFiddle  всё нормально. Не возражаешь, если твою графику попробую?

Comment: сто баксоф на счёт!!!)

Comment: Красота!.......